# Accessing actions with prefixes in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

im still noob with cakephp. I want to access an action with a prefix but im being redirected to my current view. how can i do this? Example:

ihave a function like below:

function admin_getID()
{
some codes here...
}

in my link. i accessed it using this html helper:

$this->Html->url(array('action'=>'getID', 'admin'=>true))

note that currently i dont have any prefix and i want to access the action with a prefix.

the url will be used in jQuery.ajax's URL so in the jquery,

jQuery.ajax({
    ...
    url:"Html->url(array("action"=>"getID", "admin"=>true))?>",
    ...
});

Thank you!

Comment: How you are trying to access this action? Show some code.

Comment: hi paulo! i edited some details. kindly check for it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your file **core.php** you are using the same prefix, for example:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

You should use:

```
echo $this->Html->link('link', array('action' => 'getID', 'admin' => true));
```

This will generate the link `/admin/{your_controller}/getID`.

For the same Controller, but if you want to display to another controller, you must include the `controller` parameter in the array.

If you're not using the directive `Routing.prefixes` as I said above, simply add the `admin_getID` parameter in action value.

Comment: this will redirect me to my current location. anyways i found some answer using $this->Auth->allow() but is there any better solution than using this so that i can access the prefixed action in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about routing. So for example, if you want to define actions for admin like:

```
admin_index
admin_edit
admin_view
```

adn have them accessible by

```
example.com/admin/index
example.com/admin/edit
example.com/admin/view
```

This is called routing in CakePHP. You can see how this is done here:

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/948/Defining-Routes

**Update**

You can just do this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('link', array('controller' => '{CONTROLLER_NAME}', 'action' => 'getID', 'admin' => 'true')); ?>
```

**UPDATE 2**

You are not echoing your URL. You need to do this:

```
jQuery.ajax({ ... url:"<?php echo $this->Html->url(array("action"=>"getID", "admin"=>true)); ?>", ... });
```

If you are not using PHP to render your jQuery, you cannot use cake to generate your URL, you will have to do it manually:

```
jQuery.ajax({ ... url:"/admin/CONTROLLER/getID", ... });
```

Comment: hi chuck. thank you for the reply. kindly check for the details again, i edited some part. thanks

Comment: actually im using the url for jquery.ajax so in my jQuery.ajax i have a url:"<?php echo $this->Html->url(array("action"=>"getID", "admin"=>true))?>"

Comment: It would be more helpful if you include all the details in the post instead of one piece at a time. There is nothing more we can do to help until you provide more information as to what you are looking for.

Comment: sorry i didnt include the jquery detail thing 'coz i think it is not necessary for you (cakephp programmer) to know more about it.